# Refresh component in angular - google Authentication - navigate to internal page after authentication

Tags: google-authentication, angular11

I have the following problem. Perhaps I have not understood well how Angular works.
I have inserted Google Authentication in my code and it works. Then the JWT is sent to a Back-end in C# and I receive correctly the JWT from my back-end. Based on the right authentication and authorization, then I want to navigate to the internal page. But I do not succeed immediately, but only when I press **F5**, because in **OnInit** there is a **Redirect** function.

This is the code. I owrk with Angular 11.

Login Component

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck {
  user: BehaviorSubject<User>;


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myRedirectTo();
  }

  myRedirectTo(): void  {
    let returnUrl = "";
    if (this.user != null)
      {
 
        if (this.user.value.ruolo == "ascritto") 
            returnUrl =Path.AscrittiHome;
        else if (this.user.value.ruolo == "segretario")     
          returnUrl = Path.SegretariHome;
        else if (this.user.value.ruolo == "amministratore")     
            returnUrl = Path.AmmininistratoreHome;
        if (returnUrl !== ""){

          this.router.navigate([returnUrl] );
 
        }
      }
  }
  
  async checkUser(): Promise<void> {
    const user = await this.authenticationService.checkUserRole$(this.selectedRole); 
    this.setUser(user);  

   }


  async authenticateGoogle(): Promise<void> {
    await this.authenticationService.authenticateGoogle();
    await this.checkUser();
   
    this.myRedirectTo();

  }
}
```

Then the login.component.html is very easy

```
 <mat-card-actions >
        <button  mat-button style="padding: 1rem;" (click)="authenticateGoogle()">
          <mat-icon style="width: 50px; height:30px"
                    svgIcon="logo"></mat-icon> Login With Google
          </button> 
      </mat-card-actions>
```

Also the authentication.service is very easy

```
  public checkUserRole$(ruolo: string): Promise<User> {
    
      const baseApiUrl = environment.baseapiUrl;
      const ApiPath = apiRoutes.authCheckAscrittoRuolo;
      let user = new BehaviorSubject<User>(
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"))
      ).value;
      user.ruolo = ruolo;
      return this.http.post<User>(`${baseApiUrl}${ApiPath}`,
           user).toPromise();
      
  }
```

When I click on the button **Login with Google**, I am authenticated, but the page is not reloaded. No errors are displayed.

Then,  because I save the user in memory, when I reload the page, **myRedirectTo()** is called and the right internal page is shown.

Where is the problem? What have I not understood well?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed completely the approach.

In the app.component.ts

```
   constructor(authService: AuthenticationService) {
      if (authService.isLoggedIn) {
      authService.myRedirectTo();
    }
   }
```

In the authentication.service.ts

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class AuthenticationService {
  private userSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;
  private isLogged: boolean;

  constructor( private http: HttpClient, 
    private authService: SocialAuthService,
    private router: Router
    ) {
    this.userSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(
      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"))
    );
    if (this.userValue != null) {this.isLogged = true;}
    else {this.isLogged = false;}
  }

  public get isLoggedIn(): boolean
  {
    return this.isLogged;
  }

  public get userValue(): User {
    return this.userSubject.getValue();
  }

  private signInWithGoogle() {
    return this.authService.signIn(GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID);
  }

     
  public logout(): void {
    // remove user from local storage to log user out
    localStorage.removeItem("user");
    this.userSubject.next(null);
    this.isLogged = false;
  }

  public async authenticateGoogle(ruolo: string): Promise<void>  {
    let user: User = new User();
    await this.signInWithGoogle()
    .then(res => {
      user.tokenExtProvider= res.idToken;
      user.email= res.email;
      user.provider= "google";
      user.ruolo = ruolo;
      }
    )
    
    const userAUth: User = await this.checkUserRole$(user);
  
    if (userAUth)
        {
          this.userSubject.next(userAUth);
          localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(this.userSubject.value));
          this.isLogged= true;
          this.myRedirectTo();
        }
  }

  private async checkUserRole$(user: User): Promise<User> {
    
      const baseApiUrl = environment.baseapiUrl;
      const ApiPath = apiRoutes.authCheckAscrittoRuolo;
      return await this.http.post<User>(`${baseApiUrl}${ApiPath}`,
           user).toPromise();
      
  }

  public  myRedirectTo(): void  {
    let returnUrl: String = "";
    if (this.userValue != null)
      {
        if (this.userValue.ruolo == "ascritto") 
            returnUrl =Path.AscrittiHome;
        else if (this.userValue.ruolo == "segretario")     
          returnUrl = Path.SegretariHome;
        else if (this.userValue.ruolo == "amministratore")     
            returnUrl = Path.AmmininistratoreHome;
        if (returnUrl !== ""){
          this.router.navigate([returnUrl]);
        }
      }
  }
    
}
```

Then login.component

```
 import { AuthenticationService } from "../../core/services/authentication.service";
  
@Component({
  selector: "app-login",
  templateUrl: "login.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["login.component.css"],
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck {
  loginForm: FormGroup;
  loading = false;
  submitted = false;
  selectedRole: string;
  user: BehaviorSubject<User>;
     
  constructor(
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
    ) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
 
  async authenticateGoogle(): Promise<void> {
    await this.authenticationService.authenticateGoogle(this.selectedRole);
  }
}
```

HTML is always the same